# Convert Universe/report BO to Cube/report MS BI or the contrary

Tags: business-objects, msbi

My first question is to know if you can help to know if it's possible to convert Universe BO to Cube SSAS or The contrary?

My second question is: is it possible to convert a webi report to SSRS report or the contrary?

If you have some documentation about that I'll take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I am not familiar with any tool that would convert the either a universe/cube or WebI/SSAS report.  I would expect that this is because the structures in each of the environments are completely different.

You could do this yourself, which from what I understand is the only option.